# Creating SQLite Database table with Foreign Keys?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, foreign-keys

getting errors like unknown column "TitleID" in foreign key definition

```
    database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +
            " (TitleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            C_TITLE_NAME + " text) ");

    database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_ITEM +
            " (ItemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            C_ITEM_NAME + " text, " +
            " FOREIGN KEY (TitleID) REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID)) ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you atre trying to reference a column named ID that just does not exist in the first table. first you need to create a column corresponding to TitleID in the second table (I just named it "TitleID_ref") and then you need to reference it correctly in your last line of code.

try this

```
 database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +
        " (TitleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        C_TITLE_NAME + " text) ");

database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_ITEM +
        " (ItemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        C_ITEM_NAME + " text, " +
        "TitleID_ref INTEGER,"+
        " FOREIGN KEY (TitleID_ref) REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + "(TitleID )) ");
```

here you get the official [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) on this for sqlite